# Speed of Calculating rows in MySQL

Tags: mysql, rows

I wanted to know that does MySQL store and update the total number of rows each time a row is added or removed, or does it count rows when asked?
I'm asking this because, if it counts, it will impact applications with speed. If there are 2 million rows, it will take time to count?
So what does it do?
Thanks. :D

Comment: Instead of thinking whether it takes a long time, why not build a 2 million rows table and run a query? Also, while I'm sure that your idea is the new Twitter, but obsessing over this is overkill. It's really micro-micro-optimization.

Comment: ok.. i'll try it some day... LOL... :D

Comment: Dynamically generating it with your server-side language should be too troublesome. Run a giant incrementing loop, go to lunch, and call your mother, telling her how you managed to make a giant user-base in a single day.

Comment: good idea... but i dont want to implement it right now. got the answer from @souldmerge. But thanks for your input. :D LOL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on your storage engine. MyISAM keeps track of the row count, while InnoDB counts. But you should rather benchmark and see if it is really as slow as you think. I would think that there are much worse queries in your application than counting rows - *especially* if it takes a long time.

Comment: thanks for the info. it doesn't take time now to count, but i was just thinking when there are too many rows in a table what would happen. but thanks. it helped :D